# How to increment a variable

Tags: php, loops

I need to update a script I just received and there are tons of hardcoded loops I want to get rid of but I'm stuck with the increment of variables I have to deal with.

Variables I have i.e.

```
$totalcat1m1
$totalcat2m1
$totalcat3m1
....
```

What I want to do is to increment the number in this variable to get rid of manual written loops.

I thought I could work with `.=` but that's not working.

This is what I have now:

```
echo number_format($totalcat1m1, 2, '.', '');
echo number_format($totalcat2m1, 2, '.', '');
echo number_format($totalcat3m1, 2, '.', '');
...
```

This is what I want to do:

```
while($x <= 150) {
    echo number_format($totalcat?add_value_x_here?m1, 2, '.', '');
    $x++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) in PHP:

```php
$totalcat1m1 = 2222;
$totalcat2m1 = 2223;
$totalcat3m1 = 2224;

for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $varName = sprintf('totalcat%dm1', $i);
    echo number_format($$varName, 2, '.', '') . "\n";
}

// Output:
// 2222.00
// 2223.00
// 2224.00
```